# How would it be possible that adaptive cards in Microsoft Teams for Android never be cropped (using c#)?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

In Microsoft Teams for Windows the Adaptive Cards look like this:

[image]

And in Microsoft Teams for Android the same Adaptive Cards look this way:
[image]

I'm using LG-files (Microsoft Language Generation files) and Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.

Is there a solution to prevent that adaptive cards were being cropped in Microsoft Teams for Android?

Here is the code of the first part:

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "ActionSet",
                        "actions": [
                            {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "Ja, einverstanden.",
                                "data": {
                                    "msteams": {
                                        "type": "messageBack",
                                        "text": "Ja, einverstanden.",
                                        "displayText": "Ja, einverstanden."
                                    }
                                }                                   
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "ActionSet",
                        "actions": [
                            {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "Nein",
                                "data": {
                                    "msteams": {
                                        "type": "messageBack",
                                        "text": "Nein",
                                        "displayText": "Nein"
                                    }
                                }                                   
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "ActionSet",
                        "actions": [
                            {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "Weitere Infos",
                                "data": {
                                    "msteams": {
                                        "type": "messageBack",
                                        "text": "Weitere Infos",
                                        "displayText": "Weitere Infos"
                                    }
                                }                                   
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.0"
}
```

Thank you Tim Cadenbach. Your example looks like this on Android:

[image]

This means that only the first button was displayed and it was cropped.
On Windows, it Looks like this:

[image]

The first and second buttons have been cropped.

All buttons are located one above the other and not side by side.

I considered adding a case distinction and programming other adaptive cards for mobile devices. How can I find out what device it is? With channels from Microsoft.Bot.Connector I can find out that the channel is MS Teams. But how the device?

Comment: Are you able to post the json for your card? It's possible that it has "wrap" set to "false", in which case it will NOT wrap the text, and will make it wide

Comment: Yea Hilton is right, you need to make sure you use "Wrap":true

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: @Hilton Giesenow: Where in my code would you add the wrap command?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of Mobile adaptive card actions. Adaptive card renders the buttons according to the width of the screens and provides you a scroll bar below to scroll through the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:

This is a known issue in the MS Teams Mobile App already raised with the team here:
https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3919

Someone is working on it and it should be solved in the next month.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Cadenbach.  I've checked you example. Please have a look above to see the result.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in a way. The placement of actions (horizontal/vertical) is something you can not control yourself, thats set in the hostconfig.You can hack around with columns etc but that will only work for that specific host then. You can find out if an activity comes from MS Teams but afaik not if it is for Android or Teams as such as a user can view your card in both the app and desktop. 

However it should not crop buttons like it does on android, that honestly looks like an issue for me. There's a similar issue already here: https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/4107

Comment: Actually someone raised it as an issue already : https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3919

This should be fixed in June sprint so you can expect it some time in July i guess